# If $u, v, w$ are distinct vectors, $S =\{u, v\}$ is L.I. Prove if $T= \{u, v, w\}$ is L.D then $w \in$ span(S)

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that $T$ has more vectors than it needs to span its space, that's what it means to be dependent. so I write w i.t.o the first two vectors, $w = \left(-\frac{a_1}{a_3}\right)u - \left(\frac{a_2}{a_3}\right)v$. i'm not sure what my next step should be. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $T$ is L.D, $\exists$ scalars $a,b,c$ not all are $0$ such that: $au + bv + cw = 0$. If $c = 0$, then $au+ bv = 0$, and not both $u,v$ are $0$ since not all $a,b,c$ are $0$. Thus $u,v$ are L.D, contradiction. So $c \neq 0$, and this gives $w = (-c^{-1}a)u + (-c^{-1}b)v \in \text{span}(u,v) = \text{span}(S)$.